# MongoDB, replace state names with abbreviations

Tags: mongodb

I want to update a collection so that an address uses state abbreviations, *"AK"*, rather then the long names, *"Alaska"*.

How can I do an updateMany with logic to handle this?

*pseudo code*

```
const states = [
  {name:"Alaska", abbreviation:"AK"},
  {name:"Alabama", abbreviation:"AL"},
...
Users.updateMany({"address.state": {$nin: states.abbreviation},
{$set: {"address.state": { states.find(state => state.name == address.state).abbreviation } } }
}
```

Comment: Would running two queries be acceptable? One to get it all, sort it with `js`, and then second to update the entire document?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bulk writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) with 50 `updateMany` commands. You do need one command per state but you can send them to the server in a single operation.